# Directory.GetFiles(path, ".txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories); doesn't deliver a file

Tags: c#

How would I search all the files in directory and all its sub directories for a specific extension

```
Directory.GetFiles(path, ".txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

The code above returns no files

Comment: `(path, "*.txt")` ?

Comment: Try *.txt ..............

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe its your search pattern or second parameter.  should be "*.txt".

```
Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Answer (score 9):

you need to use wild card notation

```
Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

in your case you're searching for files ".txt" name, instead you need tell to API to retrieve to you all files that has `txt` extension.

Answer (score 7):

Because you're searching literally for the file named `.txt`

Use a wildcard character like so: `*.txt` and it should pull up any `.txt` files.

See documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The filter needs to be "*.txt":

```
Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @tigran and others says you need to use wild card notation. However the difference between .NET Framework and .NET should be mentioned. See table below.

> .NET Framework only: When you use the asterisk wildcard character in
> searchPattern and you specify a three-character file extension, for
> example, "*.txt", this method also returns files with extensions that
> begin with the specified extension. For example, the search pattern
> "*.xls" returns both "book.xls" and "book.xlsx". This behavior only
> occurs if an asterisk is used in the search pattern and the file
> extension provided is exactly three characters. If you use the
> question mark wildcard character somewhere in the search pattern, this
> method returns only files that match the specified file extension
> exactly. The following table depicts this anomaly in .NET Framework.

| Files in directory | Search pattern | .NET 5+ returns | .NET Framework returns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| file.ai, file.aif | *.ai | file.ai | file.ai |
| book.xls, book.xlsx | *.xls | book.xls | **book.xls, book.xlsx** |
| ello.txt, hello.txt, hello.txtt | ?ello.txt | ello.txt, hello.txt | ello.txt, hello.txt |

In .NET Framework you can use this code to filter the results:

```
Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(filePath => filePath.EndsWith(".txt"));
```

Source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-8.0#system-io-directory-getfiles(system-string-system-string)